# Jest can't resolve import token inside module

Tags: typescript, jestjs

My app has a structure that use core code from separate dependency in package.json.
For example, my unit-test file has an `import` inside it like that

```
import {SomeComponent} from 'core-pr/base-components/baseComponent';
```

where `core-pr` is located in `node_modules/core-pr` directory.
And that `baseComponent.ts` file is loaded successfully and parsed as well good. But inside `baseComponent.ts` there is relative dependency like

```
import {Helper} from './baseHelper';
```

and it can not be resolved with error message - `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`.

But if I replace `import {Helper} from './baseHelper'` to `const ... = require('./baseHelper')` - it works.

Jest settings are:

```
"jest": {
   "globals": {
     "ts-jest": {
       "tsConfigFile": "tsconfig.spec.json"
     },
     "__TRANSFORM_HTML__": true
   },
   "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
   "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jest/setupJest.ts",
   "transformIgnorePatterns": [
     "node_modules/(?!core-pr/src)"
   ],
   "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
   "transform": {
     "^.+\\.ts$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js",
     ".*\\.svg$" : "<rootDir>/jest/transformers/svgTransformer.js"
   },
   "testRegex": "",
   "testMatch": ["<rootDir>/src/**/*.unit.ts"],
   "moduleFileExtensions": [
     "ts",
     "js"
   ]
}
```

Has anybody an advice regarding this relative import resolving from outside dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an investigation, I detected that `transformIgnorePatterns` in my config file is not correct. To resolve I should change this

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
   "node_modules/(?!core-pr/src)"
],
```

to

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
   "node_modules/core-pr/node_modules/"
],
```